# Poison Pills in ArrayBlockingQueue with type Runnable

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a blocking queue that contains tasks to perform:

```
private final BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(20);
private final AtomicInteger isPoisingPill = new AtomicInteger(2); //two producers
```

There is also a consumer:

```
while (isPoisingPill.get() != 0) {
     processExecutor.submit(this.kpiData.take()));
}
```

Each provider when completing a job, make: `isPoisingPill.decrementAndGet();`

But it does not work in all cases. There are times when we went into the cycle, the producer put the PoisingPill in false, and the program hangs, because the operation `take()` waiting for the element in the queue, and it is not, because the producer have finished. It turns out, the pill should be put directly in the queue, and in the cycle is already checked for equality. But what should I put there if the queue contains only `Runnable` objects?

There is also a situation when I have a lot of producers. We need to wait for them to complete.

Comment: Poising? Do you mean poison?

Comment: I mean: Poison Pill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, poison pill should be added to the queue with tasks.
You can create your own class extending `Runnable` and having Boolean flag

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
  private boolean posionPill = false;

  public Boolean isPosionPill() {
    return poisonPill;
  }
  ..... // your other stuff
}
```

And when you call `take()` check that flag before starting execution of `Runnable`

Another option is to have

```
public static final Runnable POISON_PILL = new Runnable() { 
  public void run(){}
};
```

somewhere in your code and add that static object to queue and after `take()` compare object from queue with that constant

And in consumer you need to do something like this

```
int pillsCount = 0;
while (pillsCount < 2) {
  MyRunnable task = queue.take();
  if (task.isPoisonPill()) {
    ++pillsCount;
  } else {
    executor.submit(task);
  }
}
```

Comment: In this case, there is another big problem. One producer will send the poison pill before the other producer, the cycle will end, but the second producer is still working!

Comment: @All_Safe consumer should stop only when it got the same number of pills as there are producers. So in your case consumer should stop after receiving two poison pills

Comment: Ok, I thought so! But how to check this number in a cycle?

Comment: No need for every task object to carry around a boolean flag, and no need to write extra code to test it.  The poison pill can just be an object with a `run()` method that initiates the shutdown process.

Comment: @besmirched is this particular case consumer should receive 2 poison pills to stop working. Also tasks producer should not know anything about internals of tasks consumer. And without such knowledge it is hard to start shutdown process

Comment: Indeed. That task producer should not know the consumer's internals. In fact, it should not even know that there is any such thing as a "poison pill." The consumer should provide a public method with "shutdown" in its name. The producer only needs to know to call it. The shutdown method is where all of the knowledge of poison pills and other details of shutting down are contained.